# System.__ComObject instead of active directory values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap, adsi

I tried to fetch LDAP user information using asp . But I get System.__ComObject instead of active directory values. Please help me to solve this .

**CODE**

I'm getting System.__ComObject instead of active directory values . Please help me to solve this error .

Comment: You're using `&` in the first and `+` in the second `If` but you're expecting the same result ? Just change `+` to `&`

Comment: sorry it's typo error . I used & but the issue is oRS.fields("givenName") it's throwing error

Comment: what is the error ? update the question title and the question body to include the new error. Specify which row throws the error. Thanks !

Comment: @reportgunner can you tell me how to get the value instaed of system._comobject

Comment: I think you have to loop all of the fields and read their value like `For Each field in oRS.fields` and `field.Value()`

Comment: @reportgunner not working for me :(

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819458/how-to-get-a-system-comobject-value-from-active-directory-in-c-sharp, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441110/why-am-i-getting-system-comobject-from-my-ldap-property